# Gnome Software - "Unable to Install As Not Supported" Message

Tags: fedora, gnome, nvidia

I was unable to find a match for my issue via search, so I am posting a new question.  My apologies if this is a duplicate.

I am running Fedora 31 and every time I open the Gnome Software Center, I am presented with a message that says, "Unable to install "NVIDIA Linux Graphics Driver" as not supported"

[image: Gnome software Unable to Install Message]

The thing is, it is listed as being installed already.  I checked the Installed section and it's listed at the bottom.  Plus the Installed section, keeps showing a 1 as if something needs my attention, but I see nothing there.

[image: NVIDIA Driver Showing As Installed]

[image]

So my question is, how do I get this message to go away?  Should I simply try uninstalling & re-installing the Nvidia Driver?  Is there a log I can check to see why it is failing?  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem (but with Celluloid's flatpak). To solve it I:

1. Killed `gnome-software` from the system monitor
2. Deleted the file in `~/.local/share/gnome-software/install_queue`

Comment: +1, solved it for me - also the blue number in the "Installed" tab header is now removed.

Comment: This solved it for me as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I got the exact same "unable to install as not supported" message when trying to install both 510 and 470 nvidia drivers in Fedora 36 through the Software Center. The way I fixed it was to follow the instructions at https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/NVIDIA. In particular:

```
sudo dnf update -y # and reboot if you are not on the latest kernel
sudo dnf install akmod-nvidia # rhel/centos users can use kmod-nvidia instead
sudo dnf install xorg-x11-drv-nvidia-cuda #optional for cuda/nvdec/nvenc support
```

After doing the above, when I opened Gnome software center again, I noticed that the latest "Nvidia Graphics Driver" was automatically installed.